# SQL Query not working if ID longer than 2 digits

Tags: mysql

I`m currently writing a simple pm system which works fine except for 1 query.

I want to get a list of conversations and display a preview of the latest post in each conversation. Now the query below works fine as long as the message ids are anywhere between 1 - 99 but as soon as it reaches 100 it won`t return the messages with ids higher than 99 in the result.

Does anyone have an idea why it stops working when the id of the database row gets higher than 2 digits or even a solution would be great.

This is my current query:

```
SELECT userid, partnerid, max(latestmsg) as postdate, type, message, m.firstname, m.lastname FROM (
SELECT sentfrom as userid, sentto as partnerid, max(postdate) as latestmsg, type, message FROM chatmessages GROUP BY sentfrom, sentto
UNION 
SELECT sentto as userid, sentfrom as partnerid,max(postdate) as latestmsg, type, message FROM chatmessages GROUP BY sentto, sentfrom
) chatmsg
LEFT JOIN members m on chatmsg.partnerid = m.memberid
WHERE userid = '1'
AND partnerid != '1'
AND type = '1'
GROUP BY userid, partnerid
ORDER BY latestmsg DESC
```

I would be really greatful for any advice.

Comment: no it doesn`t give an error. it just doesnt return the rows with a higher id. If i set all message ids higher than 99 it just returns an empty result (MySQL lieferte ein leeres Resultat zurück (d.h. null Datensätze). (Die Abfrage dauerte 0.0031 Sekunden.)

Comment: what is the data type of sentto & sentfrom ? why are you using strings **'1'** instead of integers?

Comment: oh and you are right actually the datatype is INT but since i had so many strings in the other queries i forgot about it here. I have changed it in my code now as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work any better?

```
SELECT
      l.userid
    , l.partnerid
    , l.postdate
    , c.type
    , c.message
    , m.firstname
    , m.lastname
FROM (
      SELECT
            userid
          , partnerid
          , MAX(postdate) AS postdate
      FROM (
            SELECT
                  case when sentfrom = '1' then sentfrom else sentto end AS userid
                , case when sentfrom = '1' then sentto else sentfrom end AS partnerid
                , postdate
            FROM chatmessages
            WHERE (
                    (sentfrom = '1' AND sentto <> '1')
                  OR
                    (sentto = '1' AND sentfrom <> '1')
                  )
                  AND type = '1'
            ) AS raw
      GROUP BY
            userid
          , partnerid
      ) as l
INNER JOIN chatmessages c on (
                              ( l.userid = c.sentfrom and l.partnerid = c.sentto )
                             or 
                              ( l.userid = c.sentto and l.partnerid = c.sentfrom )
                             )
                             and c.type = '1' and c.postdate = l.postdate
INNER JOIN members m ON l.partnerid = m.memberid
;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot this one works perfect now. in your answer in the last line you forgot to chnage chatmsg to l  like chatmsg.partnerid = m.memberid to l.partnerid = m.memberid but i changed this and now it works. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: fixed that copy paste error, thanks. pleased the query works for you.